# CCEaseInOut animation in cocos2d-X

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am porting a game from cocos2d to cocos2d-X. I am trying to port the following code

```
id scaleXAction =  [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:kDuration1 scaleX:1.0 scaleY:1.0] rate:kRate];
id scaleYAction = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:kDuration2 scaleX:1.0 scaleY:kScaleY2] rate:kRate];
```

In cocos2d-X the CCEaseInOut code only takes a float entry in the create function? Can anyone please help me convert the code ?

Kind Regards

Comment: Sample code would be: `CCAction* scaleXAction =  CCEaseInOut::create(CCScaleTo::create(kDuration1, 1.0f 1.0f), kRate);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cocos2dX you can try this code:

```
CCSize screenSize   = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getVisibleSize();

float   x = screenSize.width;
float   y = screenSize.height;

CCActionInterval* action =  CCEaseInOut::create(CCScaleTo::create(2.1f,x*2,y*3),1.2f);
sprite->runAction(action);
```